# Bidirectional Socket (multicast TX and unicast RX)

Tags: sockets, udp

I am wondering if the following is possible regarding the creation of a socket that should provide the following:

1. send multicast UDP **only** a particular interface (eth1).
2. receive UDP (both unicast and multicast) **only** on another interface (eth2).

By understanding is that Point 1 can be achieved by doing sesockopt with IP_MULTICAST_IF that contains the desired interface.

On the other hand, to receive from the other interface one should invoke bind.

Is this setup going to work? There is no logical contradiction between IP_MULTICAST_IF (on eth1 let's say for TX) and bind (on eth2 for RX) ?

Thanks,

Comment: You will need two sockets for that.

Comment: Would you be nice to explain why? Accoding to the manual: 

IP_MULTICAST_IF is used to specify the outgoing interface to send multicast while SO_BINDTODEVICE is used for receiving.

Comment: Can someone please explain to me why is not possible?